¿Cómo se llama (si es que tiene nombre) al hecho de llamar a los objetos por su nombre?
Por ejemplo, cuando evitamos el uso excesivo de palabras que sustituyen a los nombres, como "cosa(s)".
En lugar de decir: "esta cosa está bonita", decir "esta taza está bonita".
En ese caso, preferimos llamar al objeto por su nombre.
A esa acción me gustaría saber si tiene algún nombre y cuál es.

denominar  Significa señalar algo con su título.  Es un poco más limitado que nombrar.

Es un verbo y claro que existe.
Nombrar

verbo transitivo
Decir el nombre de alguien o algo.

También se puede usar como

verbo transitivo
Hacer mención particular, generalmente honorífica, de alguien o algo.


Se dice hablar con propiedad, usualmente se usa en imperativo por lo que quedaría algo así:

Cómo es eso de ‘cosa’? Hable con propiedad, se dice taza.

También se puede decir el famoso dicho al pan, pan y al vino, vino, con la misma idea.
